# Should I transition to platfom version from support library when supporting API above 14?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have  until recently supported older versions of android and for that purpose I made extensive use of android support library. One example I am interested in is the use of:

```
android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager
android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader
android.support.v4.content.Loader
android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader
```

And in my AppCompatActivity I use method like:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID_RETAIL, null, this);
```

As I have dropped the support for android versions before 4.1 I asked myself is it a wise choice to refactor my application and use native platform versions of the above? The platform supported classes of newer API's are:

```
android.app.LoaderManager
android.content.CursorLoader
android.content.Loader
android.content.AsyncTaskLoader
```

One consideration is that across different versions (4.1 up to 7.x) this classes might be implemented differently and behave differently and cause errors. If I stick ti support library the same implementation (code) of support library is used across all devices. Any experience or thoughts or definite answers on these.

Another consideration is that I still intend to use AppCompatActivity from support library as it has support for toolbar UI pattern and the layouter inflates support library versions of widgets. Will there be any clashes If I drop android.supoort.v4.* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO it's wise to continue to use the support library versions anyway regardless of your minSdk version - the support library is regularly updated and likely has various bug fixes compared to the shipped platform versions.

As you say as well, it means that you can rely on one implementation.

The only upside that I can see to dropping the support libraries and using the platform implementation is a smaller APK/lower method count, which may or may not be worth it for you.

Comment: I accepted your answer because you were first. Both you and TruongHieu confirmed my thoughts. Therefore upvote for both.

Comment: @user6694745 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use all support version. Because Google often update and fix bugs support version, while platform version does not.